# CI3 - Remove the image tags

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a database of blogs.  In the body field, I have html.  Essentially, it is the body of the blog post with all the markup, including  tags that references the path to various images.  In the admin area, I have a list of posts but in the list I don't want to to display any of the images.

Here is an example of the 'body' field:

```
<p>This is some text.  This is a pict.  <img alt="" 
src="/ckfinder/userfiles/images/picts.jpg" xss="removed"></p>
```

There could be more than one image and in various formats.

Also, how can I get the value of 'body' without it rendering the html?  Whenever I say, $item['body'] the html is rendered but I would like to see the html instead.

Comment: in php you can echo this in the head of the webpage to hide all images

    `<style>
    img{display:none;}
    </style>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS, you may target images in the admin area where the post is displayed to hide them.

```
.admin-area .post-body img {
    display:none;
}
```

But there would be no need to do the above if you choose to use either of the below functions.

If you would like to display the post body without rendering the HTML:

- To show text only: `strip_tags($item['body']);`
- To show HTML as text: `htmlspecialchars($item['body']);`